# Differential Equation : method of Constant variation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve $y'' + 4y = 5\cos(2x)$. I solved first the homogenous equation and I find $y_H=C_1\cos(2x)+C_2\sin(2x)$. Then i can do two methods :

1) The undetermined coefficients: I find my particular solution $y_p =\frac{5}{4}x\sin(2x)$, which is the correct solution.

2) The constant variation: I suppose $y_p=C_1(x)\cos(2x) + C_2(x)\sin(2x)$, I compute $y_p'$ and $y_p''$ then I apply the method and now I find that $C_1(x)=-\frac{5}{16}\cos(4x)$ and $C_2(x)=\frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{8}\sin(4x)$. Then my $y_p$ is different.

Can someone show me how to apply the constant variation step by step to this differential, because I really tried to see why I get a wrong result and I don't get it.

EDIT : My work for method 2 : $y_p = C_1(x)cos(2x) + C_2(x)sin(2x)$

$y_p'=C_1'cos(2x)+C_2'sin(2x)-2C_1sin(2x)+2C_2cos(2x)$

I deliberately choose that $C_1'\cos(2x)+C_2'sin(2x)=0$

$y_p''=-2C_1'sin(2x)+2C_2'cos(2x)-4C_1cos(2x)-4C_2sin(2x)$

Then i get $C_1'\cos(2x)+C_2'sin(2x)=0$ and $-2C_1'sin(2x)+2C_2'cos(2x)=5cos(2x)$ which is a simple system.

$C_1'=-5/2sin(2x)cos(2x)$

$C_2'=5/2cos(2x)^2$

I integrate and find $C_1=5/16cos(4x)$ and $C_2=5/4x + 5/16 sin(4x)$. Then i replace it in my particular solution which gives me $y_p=5/16cos(4x)cos(2x)+(5/4x + 5/16 sin(4x))sin(2x)$.

Hope it's more clear.

Thank you.

Comment: $y=\frac54\cos(2x)$ is **NOT** a solution of the full equation.

Comment: @Did Yes it's the particular solution i have to add it to yh to have the complete solution but in the second case yp is false

Comment: It is not a particular solution.

Comment: Please include your working in reaching that solution. As an aside though, I wouldn't recommend using method 2 for this problem, method 1 is much nicer.

Comment: @john yes i know that it's much nicer but i don't understand why it doesn't work with method 2. My work is useless because i really need to see step by step what to do to understand.

Comment: No problem. Your work might not be correct, but by seeing it we can tell you where and why you're going wrong.

Comment: I can also confirm what @Did has said that the particular solution in method 1 isn't quite right. You can check this by substituting it into the differential equation.

Comment: A question without your work is useless because we really need to see step by step what you did to understand what you do not understand. (That, or apply my last comment.)

Comment: @Did Sorry my bad i post the wrong particular solution the good one is 5/4xSin(2x) i'll edit it now and post my work. Thank you

Comment: You still did not post how you got $y_p$ in 1. nor how you got $C_1(x)$ and $C_2(x)$ in 2. My guess is that, if you fail to do so, a complete answer will soon be posted--which will probably not help you since what you really need are explanations about the mistake(s) **YOU** made.

Comment: I would be particularly interested of how you got C2

Comment: @Did Now i posted my work for method 2, concerning 1 don't worry i'm sure of what i did. Thank you for help !

Comment: @john Posted ;) Thank you for helping !

Comment: I think that (5/4)xsin(2x) is correct!

Comment: @imranfat Yes it is correct

Comment: First mistake: $C'_2(x)=\frac52\cos^2(2x)$, not $\frac12\cos^2(2x)$. Can you carry on after that?

Comment: Your solutions for C1' and C2' aren't right. If I substitute them into the first equation (right under A SIMPLE SYSTEM), it doesn't come out.

Comment: ok, a few issues I've already spotted with your method 2: Your solutions for $C_1'$ and $C_2'$ aren't correct- suggested $C_2'=\frac{5}{2}\cos^2(2x)$. Your integrations also aren't correct. $C_1$ I believe you're looking more at a sin function if you take the double angle approach. $C_1$ seems to be missing a factor of a half.

Comment: @john Okay i'll try it again like that. Thank you Did and john

Comment: No problem. After these latest edits you're very close to your final answer- all you need to do is apply the compound angle formula

Comment: except why did you just edit in that minus sign?

Comment: @Did Now if -5/16cos(4x)cos(2x) = 5/16sin(4x)sin(2x) my result would be good. Are you seeing a way to prove this?

Comment: see my comments above to resolve this issue (these shouldn't be equal in general)

Comment: @john I thought that was a foul maybe i'd better restart everything clearly then what i have to prove is -5/16cos(4x)cos(2x) = 5/16sin(4x)sin(2x) ?

Comment: no, they shouldn't be equal in general. Try using the compound angle formula to rewrite the entire expression (both terms). You are very close!

Comment: @ john It's useless to rewrite it while it is false when i tap on wolfram that my yp calculated in 2 is equal to 5/4xsin(2x) it says that it's false

Comment: Indeed 5/16cos(4x)cos(2x)+5/16sin(4x)sin(2x) does not cancel. But recall that you might find any particular solution $y_p$, not necessarily the one you have in mind...

Comment: @Did But the particular solution should be unique NO ?!

Comment: no, because we can add any amount of the homogeneous solution onto it and we'll still satisfy the differential equation- in fact, this is the entire basis of solving these differential equations.

Comment: Like @john said.

Comment: so that should be a bit of a clue as to what you want those other terms to end up looking like

Comment: Okay i understood. I'll try then to find how to rewrite it. If anyone of you know how please say it because i passed hours on that stupid fouls and i really want to understand it.

Comment: Again, it relies on the compound angle formula, in this case, $\cos(A-B)=\cos(A)\cos(B)+\sin(A)\sin(B)$

Comment: Oh i see it thank you !

Comment: no problem at all.

Comment: @Amzoti Yes i got my answer, Is there a way to close it?

Comment: I suppose you can flag it (see the 'flag' link to the left of your name) for a moderator. Glad you converged! Regards

Answer (score 3):

The problem was explained in the comments, but I'll post an answer for the sake of having one. The quickest solution would be by Method 1, undetermined coefficients. Since we have resonance (source term is also a solution of homogeneous  equation), our particular solution will be of the form $y=x(A\cos 2x+B\sin 2x)$. In order to write less, it helps to realize that when we plug this $y$ into equation, the terms where $x$ does not get differentiated will go away. With that thought, and the formula $(uv)''=u''v+2u'v'+uv''$ in mind, 
$$y''+4y = 2(A\cos 2x+B\sin 2x)' = -4A\sin 2x+4B\cos 2x$$
hence $A=0$ and $B=5/4$. Answer: $y=\frac54 x\sin 2x$.

As for variation of parameters, it's best to not think of it as a way to get a particular solution. The result of computations with this method (with $c_1$ and $c_2$ included in appropriate places after integration) will be the general solution.